# Is there an easy way of referring to the public directory in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Imagine this structure:

```
   /project
       /templates
          view1.haml
          view2.haml
          misc_views/
             view3.haml
             view4.haml
             even_deeper/
               view5.haml
       /public
          script1.js
```

The depth of the templates can vary, and I would like to refer to the public directory if I want to include some files from it. Is there a helper or some other gimmick that takes me to the public directory? It seems bad to have something like ../../../public/script1.js , or ../../public/script1.js in my views. Surely there must be a better way.

Comment: To be clear, you realize that it is not the relative path between the files on disk that you need to include in the HTML sent to the web browser, but rather the relative path between the served route and the root of the public directory? For example, if you have `get("/foo"){ haml 'misc_views/even_deeper/view5.haml' }` then your HTML should have `src="script1.js"` or `src="/script1.js"`.

Comment: Of course. That goes without saying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `settings.public` configuration](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__static_files_directory) to refer to the public directory. For example:

```
get "/" do
  js = File.join( settings.public, 'script1.js' )
  File.exists?( js ) #=> true
end
```

As this is an absolute path, there is no need to make it relative to your view to get the file. You could reach out to this from your view, but I would personally set the path as an instance variable from the controller.

```
get "/" do
  # If you really only need the directory
  @public = settings.public

  # If you actually need the path to a specific file
  @main = File.join( settings.public, 'main.js' )

  # If you actually need the contents of a file
  @js = IO.read( File.join( settings.public, 'main.js' ) )
end
```

Comment: For anyone following along - newer Sinatra now uses `settings.public_folder`

Answer (score 1):

You must include the static resources by the root of the web address or a relative request path, as it will be the browser who requests it, not your server-side code. Unless I am mistaken in your case?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Downvoted because (per @Geo's clarifying comment) this (otherwise correct) answer is not the answer to the question being asked.